# printing into a text file from dictionary key and values

Tags: python

I need some help with some code where it needs to go into the log file and it should look like this:

[image: example of the log file]

I have the dictonary which holds the count value and the keys which is the event id, but I want to display it like that but I do not know how to since it comes out all at once and it does not print individually instead of 1 by 1 and I have used a nested dictionary to do this.

This is an example of the dictionary which holds the count vals and keys which need to be printed.

```
eventIDs = {1102: {'count': 0}, 4611: {'count': 0}, 4624: {'count': 0}, 4634: {'count': 0}, 4648: {'count': 0}, 4661: {'count': 0},
        4662: {'count': 0}, 4663: {'count': 0}, 4672: {'count': 0}, 4673: {'count': 0}, 4688: {'count': 0}, 4698: {'count': 0},
        4699: {'count': 0}, 4702: {'count': 0}, 4703: {'count': 0}, 4719: {'count': 0}, 4732: {'count': 0}, 4738: {'count': 0},
        4742: {'count': 0}, 4776: {'count': 0}, 4798: {'count': 0}, 4799: {'count': 0}, 4985: {'count': 0}, 5136: {'count': 0},
        5140: {'count': 0}, 5142: {'count': 0}, 5156: {'count': 0}, 5158: {'count': 0}}
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
def log_output():
      with open('path' + timeStamp + '.txt', 'a') as VisualiseLog: 
        event_id = list{eventIDs.keys()}
        event_count = list(eventIDs.values)
        for item in eventIDs:
            print(f'Event ID: {event_id}')
            VisualiseLog.write('Event ID: {event_id}')
            print(f'Event Count: {event_count}')
            VisualiseLog.write(f'Event Count: {event_count}')
```

Comment: show the code you have tried

Comment: @deadshot i have added the code in the edit thanks!

Comment: @JamesCharing09 what is the issue with your current code?

Comment: @Ruan it does not work I have tried multiple things like it will print the dict into one block instead of individually as shown in the image so event id : 3232 then below it the count of how many was matched but my code does not do that and I am quite confused on how to since the code does not work or I get errors when I try some things or it just prints the code out in one go instead of individually

Comment: i have added the nested dict code, sorry about that @Reti43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
eventIDs = {
    1102: {'count': 0},
    4611: {'count': 0}
}

timeStamp = "1234"

def log_output():
    with open('path' + timeStamp + '.txt', 'a') as VisualiseLog:
        for id in eventIDs:
            count = eventIDs[id]['count']
            print(f'Event ID: {id}')
            VisualiseLog.write(f'Event ID: {id}\n')
            print(f'Event Count: {count}')
            VisualiseLog.write(f'Event Count: {count}\n\n')


log_output()



# Outputs:
#  Event ID: 1102
#  Event Count: 0
#
#  Event ID: 4611
#  Event Count: 0
```

Comment: hey bro quick one can you explain why you have done count = eventID[id]['count'] i just want to make sure I know what I am doing but honestly thank you!

Comment: @JamesCharing09 `eventIDs[id]['count']` is the value of the current event id's sub-dictionary 'count'. and `count` is the variable used in `print` and `.write`.

Comment: Also good to understand that `for id in eventIDs:` loops through the keys of the `eventID` dictionary. So in this case the values of `id` would be `1102` and `4611` respectively

Comment: cheers bro appreciate it makes sense to me now you have been a great help!